# Embedded html php syntax error while nesting if-else

Tags: php

I'm coming from Java Swing programming but I thought it would be beneficial to extend my knowledge in PHP. So, I just learned today that there's a way to embedded `html` in `php` in a much cleaner way. So what I did is follow this syntax which works okay.

```
<?php if ($condition) : ?>
 //html here
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when I nested an `if-else` to the same syntax, I get an error. By the way, I'm using PHP Storm.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($POST_['psw'])) : ?>
    //start of nested if-else
    <?php if($isValid === 1) : ?>
        <script>alert('test')</script>
    <?php else : ?> // this line shows an error
        <script>alert('test')</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
    //end of nested if-else
<?php endif; ?>
```

Below is the image of the error indicator in PHP Storm.

[image]

Error says that it expects a statement on this line

```
<?php else : ?> // this line shows an error
```

I can't figure out what causes it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is working with me. Not getting any error.

Comment: @Virb Hmm.. I don't know why it won't work on my end. Still inspecting the code if there's something I missed.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your error:

Replace this:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($POST_['psw'])) : ?>  // You are writing $POST_ but not $_POST
```

To:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['psw'])) : ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. My bad, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Glad to help. Careful for this small mistakes.

Comment: Yeah. Haha. My glasses doesn't seem to work today. =P